# Multiple Async Rely On Each Other and Promise.all() Causes Render Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have an async function that pulls data, in the form of a json, from an API. Each consecutive call is relying on what is previously returned. Sometimes when I try to access values pulled from an API, it received null since that has not fully loaded due to `async` function.

I tried to mitigate this with another `useState()` function but then it goes into a rendering loop.

The behavior I am looking for, is while the 3 sets of data are loading from the API, the `CircularProgress` is spinning. Once they are done loading, the page with information actually renders.

Load function

```
export function Load(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUrl() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchUrl();
  }, [url]);
  // console.log(data)
  return [data, loading];
}
```

main function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const main (props) => {
    const id = props.id
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const url1 = 'http://path/to/api'+id
    const [data1, loading1] = Load(url1);
    //const [data1, loading] = Load(url1) This works sometimes
    const url2 = 'http://path/to/api2' + data1.val1
    const [data2, loading2] = Load(url2)
    const url3 = 'http://path/to/api3' + data2.val1
    const [data3, loading3] = Load(url3)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    //if (loading1 === false){setLoading(false)}
    Promise.all(data2).then(setLoading(false))

    const GetValue = (props) => {
        //do something with value
        props.value=value
        console.log(value)
    }

    return(<> {loading ? (
        <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
        style={{ minHeight: '90vh' }}
      >
        <CircularProgress size="10vh" />
        </Grid>
      ) : (
          //render something
        <GetValue props={data3}/>
        )}
    );
}
export default Main
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

If I just return loading in `const [data1, loading] = DataLoader(url1);`, and get rid of `useState` and `Promise.all()`, I get this error

```
Error: GetValue(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is 
missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I don't understand how `GetValue` is getting called because `loading` is still `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

//if (loading1 === false){setLoading(false)}
Promise.all(data2).then(setLoading(false))
```

doesn't make sense. `data2` is not a promise (or an array of promises), and you're not passing a function to `then()` but are just synchronously calling `setLoading` every time the component is rerendered, which causes the infinite rendering loop.

What you want is a simple

```
const loading = loading1 || loading2 || loading3;
```

Also, you should ensure to skip the effect in your `Load` hook while the `url` is still undefined.

Comment: I tried your recommendation with ```const loading = loading1 || ...``` but I still get the ``nothing was returned from render ...``` error. Can you please elaborate on skipping effect in ```Load```. React doesn't allow hooks to be called conditionally

Comment: You haven't shown the code of `GetValue` so I don't know why it doesn't `return` anything. Regarding skipping, I didn't say to call the hook conditionally but to have an `if` inside the effect to skip it when no url (part) is passed

Comment: You are correct. I didn't have a ```render``` method typed so it failed to even ```console.log()```